# execute a script with http requests from xwiki

Tags: batch-file, curl, xwiki

I'm searching a simple way to catch informations from a repository like artifactory and put those informations in xwiki page.
In xwiki we can execute scripts but I don't know if commands like curl get/put/post can be run from the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/REST+HTTP+Client you can find Groovy script example to access a HTTP/REST service from a XWiki page.

Answer (score 0):

for GET requests you can eventually use [bitsadmin](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html) .
For more complicated http requests you should use winhttp.request  or MSXML2.XMLHTTP objects through jscript/vbscript.

Here's a [winhttp.request wrapper](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) (should be saved as .bat) that will allow you to perform get,post,delete... and so on requests with custom headers (hope its  help message will be clear enough )